# How to write _POST variable data on a PDF generated using FPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am generating a PDF using PHP and external library **[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)** and transparency script: **[alphapdf](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script74.php)**.

Code:

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" target="_blank">
     <button type="submit" formaction="print.php"> Print </button>
     <input type ="text" name="name"></input>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
require('alpha/alphapdf.php');
// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new AlphaPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetLineWidth(1.5);
// draw jpeg image
$pdf->Image('my-image.jpg',0,0,220,300,'JPG');
// print name
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$name = $_POST['$name'];
$pdf->Text(10,28,$name);
$pdf -> Output();
?>
```

Comment: so what you getting in pdf ?  echo  $_POST['name'] , to see what exactly you received.

Comment: I did echo and print_r as well, the data did got posted, but problem was in assigning to the variable, which is resolved by below answer thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this

```
$name = $_POST['$name'];
```

should be

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

try `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` for proof. 
also try to print `$_POST['$name']`